# How to understand and approach $f(x)=\int _{a} ^{b}f(y) dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x)=\int _{a} ^{b}f(y) dy$

In this case $x$ does not appear in the function in integration.
So is this only mean for all $x$ the evaluation is same?

Comment: Do $b$ or $a$ depend on $x$?

Comment: I guess if the interval does not depend on $x$ then the evaluation is completely free. Then lets say $a \le x \le b$?

Comment: If neither $a$ nor $b$ is a function of $x$, then $f(x)$ is a constant for all $x$ in its domain.